# How do I generate a random lowercase letter in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, random

I'm new to the syntax, so that's where I need help. Conceptually, I get it. But syntax is foreign to me.

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "lowercase letter"? Just "a" .. "z"? Or all lowercase letters from the Unicode character set, for example "ä", "è" or "ð"?

Comment: You want a char? or an NSString *?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a succinct way to do it:

```
- (char)getRandomChar {
    return (char) (arc4random_uniform(26) + 'a');
}
```

This assumes you want 'a' to 'z', without any letters that have diacritical marks, such as å, ä, á, etc.

To return the character as an NSString:

```
- (NSString *)getRandomCharAsNString {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", arc4random_uniform(26) + 'a'];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would create a string "abcdefg..." and get a one character long substring at a random position.
Like this:

```
NSString *letters = @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
NSInteger index = arc4random_uniform([letters length]);
NSString *randomLetter = [letters substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(index, 1)];
```

Answer (score 1):

Objective-c is a super set of C meaning you can just use valid C code.

```
-(char)getRandomChar
{
     char test[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
     int r = arc4random() % 26;
     NSLog(@"%c", test[r]);
     return test[r];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks good

```
NSLog(@"%c",'a'+ rand() % 26);
```

Comment: Wouldn't that generate random *uppercase* letters?